# Cancan and custom route for member resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, cancan

I have a route that looks something a like:

routes.rb

```
resources :blog do
  member do
    get :dashboard, to: 'admin/postings#index'
  end

  resources :postings, only: [:index]
end
```

I'm using the cancan gem to restrict access to the blog page kinda like this:

ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.has_role?(:blog_admin, :any)
    can :access, Blog, id: user.blog.id
    can :access, Posting, blog_id: user.blog.id
  end
end
```

The problem I'm running into is the path `blog/:id/postings` works just fine and I have access to it, but `blog/:id/dashboard` gives me an access denied error. If I'm routing through the same controller, why would it matter what the url is?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out. The route being generated by rails for the dashboard looked something like this, `blog/:id/dashboard`, but the route generated for the postings looked like `blog/:blog_id/postings`. So in cancan, the can method takes in a condition hash at the end where it will check to see if `params[:blog_id]` matches `user.blog.id`. This was the problem. The route I was going to only had `params[:id]` defined, not `params[:blog_id]`. So I just changed the dashboard route by removing it from the blog resource and defining it as such: `get  '/blogs/:blog_id/dashboard', to: 'admin/postings#index'`